# What is the difference between NHTTP and HTTP?

Tags: security, http, transport

What are the specific characteristics that draw the line between these two protocols?

Comment: Are you  talking about this : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clemensv/archive/2012/05/04/nhttp.aspx ?

Comment: That doesn't look right. But I'm particularly interested about NHTTP (non blocking HTTP) http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/s/Downloadsynapsenhttptransport210jar.htm http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/12/demystifying-wso2-esb-pass-thru-transport-part-ii/#nhttp

Comment: So you should Update your question because otherwise this causes confusion as there are at least three Interpretation what nhttp means

Comment: Besides that the answer stands at the top of your second link ...

Answer (score 1):

Basically you are asking "what's the difference between car and Volkswagen Golf". The two can't be compared directly.

Non blocking http (nhttp) is a specific implementation of the http protocol which (as in the name) is non blocking. There are other implementations which can be blocking but this has nothing to do with the http protocol itself

Comment: That makes sense. At the first look, it seemed to me as if nhttp has different characteristics compared to http. But is it possible to get an example where nhttp can be used but http is not applicable? I think that would make things a lot clearer.

Comment: I think this question does not make sense: "when is it good to ride a Volkswagen Golf instead of a car ?". You need non blocking I/O when your connections can - well - block, but this depends on what your application is doing.

Comment: More like I wanted to to know, what makes the Volkswagon Golf different from other cars specifically. But yes, I got what you were saying.